# How to transfer Data between Android devices using wifi direct?

Tags: wifi-direct

I need to pass String values to the devices connected through Wifi-Direct..how can i pass string between two connected device..I am using Wifi-Direct file transfer example available as reference.

In doInBackground method of FileServerAsyncTask I am using the code

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8988);
Socket client = serverSocket.accept();                 
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
```

How do i modify onHandleIntent method? Any reference to this kind of implementation will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that you should consider while sending data via wifi direct

1. Once connected, one device will be group owner and the other will be client
2. The group owner will have fixed IP address i.e. 192.168.49.1
3. You will know which became group owner only at runtime.
4. Once connected, you have to send some data from client to server that contains information about its IP address. This is done because server will have no idea of client's IP address.
5. That way, you can only send data. Because, by this time you will know which device has what IP address.

Cheers.

Comment: As you have mentioned if host contains IP address 192.168.49.1,Is it correct to use the follwing code in handle intent?      socket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(host, port)),         SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
                           
                OutputStream stream = socket.getOutputStream();
                String message = "Hello";
                byte[] buffer = message.getBytes();
                stream.write(buffer);

Comment: Yes, But provided that you are sending data to group owner. Because this is IP address of group owner

Comment: In the example given in sdk for wifiDirect they are using onClick og launch gallery `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_FILE_RESULT_CODE);` How should i change this to send a string ?